# How can I generate a large amount of standarized strings in a .txt file?

Tags: text-editors, string, generator

I'm in need of some large amount of strings generated in a .txt file.

The format is `number1:number2,`

number1 goes from 1030 up to 1130, number2 goes from 0 up to 15.

Example: `1030:0,1030:1,1030:2,...,1031:0,1031:1,...,1130:15`

How do I go about this?

Comment: I would write a simple python script for that.

Comment: What are your constraints? Do you have access to bash? perl? python? powershell? a specific text editor that accepts some scripting? It is very broad presented like that.

Comment: Windows 7, 8, 8.1 and pretty much any open-source text-editors that come to mind, like Notepad++ or stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on windows a powershell script will do nicely, with no need to install anything, just enable execution of powershell scripts;
Open powershell as admin and type "Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned" (without ").
Save the following script in a .ps1 file and right-click on it and choose "Run with PowerShell".

```
$file="Q:\Test\test.txt";
$nr1 = 1131;
$nr2 = 15;

for($i = 1030; $i -lt $nr1; $i++)
{
    $output = "";
    for($j = 0; $j -lt $nr2; $j++)
    {
        $output += "$($i):$($j),"
    }
    echo "$($output)$($i):15" >> $file;
}
```

Edit:
In answer to how you go about it, ideally you learn scripting language like, bash, powershell,batch, perl, etc.. the list goes on. Your choice depends on what platform you wanna script on/for and if you want it to be supported "out-of-the-box".

Comment: I don't really want to script anything it's just the one-time deal I have to do. I don't foresee in the future to be in need of any more scripts like that. That said, a bit of scripting know-how is never bad. Thanks for the script. I'm most of the time on Win7 and Win8(.1) if that matters.